# How to add more syntax elements for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, zend-studio

Im trying to add more syntax elements for `Zend Studio` for eclipse. I want to change the color of the equal sign and it is not listed so I can change it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to vote for http://bugs.eclipse.org/213992 as there's no way to do it without changing the source code to the preference page.