# Add to language syntax in Netbeans/Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, syntax, netbeans, callback, node.js

This may seem like seem like a bit of a weird/uncommon request but I am trying to find out if it is possible. I would like to add to the language syntax in Netbeans or Eclipse easily without needing to create an entirely new language. According to this question [How to add more syntax elements for eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281992/how-to-add-more-syntax-elements-for-eclipse) it is not possible in Eclipse, but that was asked in 2008 so maybe things have changed.

The reason I want to do it is I am developing in node.js and it uses callbacks quite heavily. So it would be nice if I could make the word 'callback' and 'callback()' be highlighted in a different colour so it can be easily seen in amongst the rest of the code.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The css thing is really easy:
go to **Options/Miscellaneous/Files**, create new file extension **less** and then select proper MIME type **text/x-css**. I Believe that it is possible to extend syntax highlighting in NetBeans IDE but you have to write your own plugin to do that.